# How to manipulate trac (web-based software project management application) data from external source/web application?

Tags: php, svn, api, trac

I was planning to implement a way to extract/update/insert [trac's](http://trac.edgewall.org/) project related data from different web application. Assuming I have direct access to database (eg. MySQL, because maybe SQLite will not work if the external site does not have access to the file system).

Is there any API for trac that I can use to manipulate milestone & ticket data, (preferably in PHP language)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin to enable XML-RPC API for almost all trac functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the plugin.

Comment: You might also take a look at the TracCmdScript, which uses the XmlRpc interface: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracCmdScript